# Multiprocessing and selenium, running multiple browsers in parallel?

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, multiprocessing, threadpool

I currently have an HTML page which I'm opening via Selenium and clicking on elements, filling out a form, and saving.

But this is slow, and I really want to speed it up. **I want to run multiple browsers at the same time**, feeding each one different `xpaths` to click on. Is this possible?

As of right now, I have a list containing three User objects. I want run 3 separate selenium processes for each user, both hitting the same web page, but clicking on different elements. And I want to do this concurrently.

Here is my code (not working):

```
def main():
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    pool.map(bookRooms, users)

...

def bookRooms(users):
    if not users:
        logging.error("No available times")
    else:
        driver = Browser('phantomjs')
        driver.visit(url)

        for user in users:
            for xpath in user.xpaths:

                driver.find_by_xpath(user.getXPath()).click()

                driver.find_by_xpath("id('save')").click()

                driver.find_by_name("username").fill(user.getUsername())

                driver.find_by_name("password").fill(user.getPassword())

                driver.find_by_name("submit").click()

        driver.close()
```

So if you imagine my list looks something like this:

```
[User1, User2, User3]
```

How can I call the `bookRooms()` method so that it runs like this in parallel:

```
bookRooms(User1)
bookRooms(User2)
bookRooms(User3)
...
```

Basically, breaking up the list and running the method on each element. And can Selenium even work in such a way?

Thank You

Answer (score -3):

I can't find anything on multithreading with Selenium+Python, but the following [Blog post](https://saucelabs.com/resources/running-your-selenium-tests-in-parallel-python) describes multiprocessing - I'd probably start there.